# Is my translation accurate? 自分の思ってる事『を』人『に』伝えられないだけじゃないんですか…？

Tags: grammar, translation, particles, english-to-japanese, interpretation

> 自分{じぶん}の思{おも}ってる事{こと}『を』人{ひと}『に』伝えられないだけじゃないんですか…？

So in this sentence ↑ : 自分{じぶん}の思{おも}ってる is attributive to 事{こと} to create:

"A thing I've been thinking about myself"

---

Since there's no word order except for emphasis, "a thing I've been thinking about myself" will be the direct object of the verb when it comes up further down the road.

人{ひと}『に』will be the indirect object of that same verb later on.

That verb in question turns out to be 伝えられない, in the passive negative form which according to my dictionary means "to declare" or in this case: "has not been declared".

---

だけ：only and じゃない: negative...

So:
**My translation:**
"There's a thing I've been thinking about myself I just have not declared to that person."

For some reason I have a feeling it's not right but it if is that would be pretty awesome as it wasn't an easy sentence.

**Source**:
https://www.sukima.me/bv/t/blackjackniyoroshiku/v/1/s/4/p/6

Comment: Please see the formatting edit. You're making life so much harder for yourself than you need to with all those html tags.

Comment: Are you trying to use 伝える as the verb?  Because AFAIK, 「云」 is only an old form of 「いう」 (云ふ, specifically).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a cursory glance at that sentence, I think it means something closer to 'Isn't it just that you can't express what you're thinking to people?'

自分の思ってること is 'a thing one is thinking', not necessarily in regards to themselves. 人 here just means 'people generally'; it's not あの人. 伝える is more 'to convey' or 'to express', and 伝えられない is indeed negative potential 'cannot express'. だけ is just or only. Yes, じゃない negates, but why did you leave out the whole んですか part from your analysis?

This ん, I *think*, sort of indicates that the interlocutor has indicated that it might be something else, and the super crucial か makes it a question - 'Isn't it ...?' rather than 'It isn't ...'